# Why no retain is needed in my code but it works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a class

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void) foo    
{    
    ivar = [NSString stringWithString:@"ivar"];
}

- (void) bar    
{    
    NSLog(@"%@", ivar);
}
```

And main.m

```
MyClass * m = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[m foo];
[m bar];
```

Why no retain is needed for stringWithString?

Can you show me an example where retain is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because the autorelease pool had no time to drain its content. Here is a crashing example:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
MyClass *m = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[m foo];
[pool drain];
[m bar];
```

The autorelease pool that holds the string in your example belongs to 99% to the current runloop which creates a new pool at the begin of the event loop and then drains it at the end.

Comment: So you mean I should write as the following for best practice: 
 ivar = [[NSString stringWithString:@"ivar"] retain];

Comment: you know that [NSString stringWithString:@"ivar"] == @"ivar", right? @"ivar" will never be deallocated, it is part of your executable.

Answer (score 2):

> Why no retain is needed for stringWithString?

Because the autorelease pool is not being drained between line 2 and line 3 (as it would be in a Cocoa app as soon as your code returns control to the run loop).

Comment: So should I write as for good practice? ivar = [[NSString stringWithString:@"ivar"] retain]

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) and look at [this](http://memo.tv/node/816) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) from Apple. In your case, you did not alloc/retain/net the NSString so you don't "own" it and therefore you do not need to release it.

Internally, NSString would return you a autoreleased object. If you don't retain it then you'll lose reference to it if it gets dealloced by an autorelease pool.

Comment: The question isn't "why don't I need to release ivar?", but "why does it seem to work even though I haven't retained ivar?" Some of the other answers here are correct: it works because ivar points to an autoreleased string, and the autorelease pool hasn't yet been drained.